# How do you browse and upload a photo from an iPhoto Library to a website using a browser like Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc

Tags: photos.app, data-transfer, web-browser

I've at a site that wants me to upload a photo.  I choose Browse... but when I get to iPhoto Library, it's opaque.  Is there some way to browse and choose one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPhoto Library folder can not be browsed directly. In Finder you can open/access it by righ-clicking and selecting the "Show Package Content" option, but this is not possible in the Open dialog.

But there is an easier way: you can access the content of your iPhoto Library directly from the file browser in the Open dialog:

[image]

This also gives you all your events, albums etc. to browse through.

Comment: Not an answer to my question.

Comment: @EricBloch Perhaps it's not the answer you sought, but I would answer about the same from my first read of your question. Can you edit some more detail into your query and see if we could help further?

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry!  Actually it is now an answer to my question!  I thought originally it only showed how to use the finder and not the dialog I got popped up from my browser.  And when I first looked, that dialog didn't have a Media section on the right.   But now, both of those things are "fixed" for me and I'm not sure I did anything to make that happen.  I see the Media section in the dialog.  And this answer seems to include a bit about the dialog.  Yay!

Answer (score 1):

In the "open" file dialog, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then in the area where you would put the filename, type `~/Pictures/iPhoto Library/` and it should open up for you.